# How to Make a Coordinate system with 4 boxes and specific text over or under it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, coordinates

I want to make a Coordinate System with 4 Boxes in it! But I am not able to:

- split the rectangle in to two part.
- Make a box without text.
- The axis should have a title[image].
  Do someone of you have a idea how to fix that?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (lang) [matrix of nodes, column sep=3mm, row sep=3mm,
    nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, rounded corners=0mm,
        fill=cyan!90!black, draw=cyan!50!black, line width=.5mm}]
{ 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\};
\draw [->, shorten >=-3mm](lang.south west)--(lang.south east); 
\node[below] at (lang.south-|lang-1-1.center) {}; 
\node[below] at (lang.south-|lang-1-2.center) {};
\draw [->, shorten >=-3mm](lang.south west)--(lang.north west);
\node[rotate=90, above] at (lang.west|-lang-2-1.center) {};
\node[rotate=90, above] at (lang.west|-lang-1-1.center) {};
\draw[dashed] (lang.south) node[below=5mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily]{}--(lang.north);
\draw[dashed] (lang.west) node[rotate=90, above=5mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily]{} --(lang.east);
%\node
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is an Example

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you maybe draw how you want the output to look like? Which rectangles to you want to split into two parts? And where exactly should the text be?

Comment: Yes, here you go! 
I now was able to draw the rectangle without text. But now i got errors like this: `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).<to be read again>l \text{ } & \text{ }\\`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`rectange split` shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split) with an (almost) empty second part.

Since the shape will ignore any `minimum height` requirement I'll just add an invisible rule of height 1.5cm. The second node part will then be 1.5cm + 2 × inner ysep high.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (lang) [
  matrix of nodes, column sep=3mm, row sep=3mm,
  every two node part/.style={execute at begin node=\rule{0pt}{1.5cm}},
  nodes={
    minimum width=3cm, fill=cyan!90!black, draw=cyan!50!black, line width=.5mm,
    rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}]{
  1 \nodepart{two} & 2 \nodepart{two} \\
  3 \nodepart{two} & 4 \nodepart{two} \\
};

\draw [<->, shorten <=-3mm, shorten >=-3mm]
     (lang.north west) node[above=3mm]{$y$}
  |- (lang.south east) node[right=3mm]{$x$}; 
\draw[dashed] (lang.south) --(lang.north)
              (lang.west) -- (lang.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!